# facebook get user mail via Facebook javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to retrieve  user mail id(using Fb javascript sdk) who is logged into fb , I did refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820485/how-to-get-email-id-of-facebook-user-using-javascript-sdk) but still i get **result as undefined**  and here is my code :

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                 alert('Your mail is ' + response.email);


                },{scope:'email'});}
);
```

Please let me know where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the email unless you have the permission to do so. You'll firstly need to request extended permissions.