# Facebook invitation callback get email address

Tags: facebook, invite

i am working with facebook invitation api using the code

```
FB.init({ 
   appId:'', cookie:true, 
   status:true, xfbml:true 
 });

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
   title : "Groups Request",
   message: 'come on man checkout my application'},requestCallback);
}

function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
        alert(response);
      }
```

The response array only get request,to and some other data. I want email addreess of invited users.

The respnose is like

Object {request: "583692088419024", to: Array[2], e2e: "{"submit_0":1400571441832}"}
e2e: "{"submit_0":1400571441832}"
request: "583692088419024"
to: Array[2]
0: "639042122836701"
1: "514439961991574"
length: 2
**proto**: Array[0]
**proto**: Object

Comment: _“I want email addreess of invited users”_ – should be pretty obvious that you will __not__ get that.

Comment: You do not have permissions to access the email address of the user that was invited because you have not requested it yet. You will not be able to get this information without having the correct permissions and access to the user.

Comment: If the user that was invited has already granted your application access, then you can retrieve their email just as you would for any other user: by making a request to `/USER_ID?fields=email`

Comment: In javascript how can i get email address please share your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820485/how-to-get-email-id-of-facebook-user-using-javascript-sdk