# Email not able to retrieve from facebook javascript SDK

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="false" 

data-scope="public_profile,email,user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState()";>
    </div>

<script>
        function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                loggedIn();

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                //User is logged into FB, but not my app
            } else {
                //User is not logged into FB
            }
        }

        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

function loggedIn(){
  FB.api('/me'),(function(response){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

 });
}


        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : <MY APP ID>,
                cookie     : true,  
                xfbml      : true, 
                version    : 'v2.5'
                });
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });

        };
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    </script>
```

For security purpose , not given my app id. This works fine and am able to retrieve user name. But I would like to retrieve the mail id .API call to /me does not retrieve the mail address. Please someone help me out if I am missing out some thing. Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry about that...edited the tags.have done using JS sdk only.

Comment: Yes I m facing the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820485/how-to-get-email-id-of-facebook-user-using-javascript-sdk but solution mentioned does not solve my problem